# Grouping Rows as Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an input file as this :

```
5181        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
6220        aaaaaaaa
1498        bbbbbbbbb 
1498        ccccccccccc
```

I want to group the lines which has same id number. So it will be like this:

```
5181        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz 
6220        aaaaaaaa
1498        bbbbbbbbbb
1498        ccccccccccc
```

I tried to create a dictionary with 3 keys but couldnt append all values.

This is what i wrote:

```
for i in package_ids:
    dict2[i] = (x for x in textt if int(i) in textt is True)
```

Comment: the lines in each group are in arbitrary odder, why?

Comment: every group has a number system also in them but just ignore it

Comment: is it ok if lines with `1498` will go first?

Comment: yes,that would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that *id* number and line's text are separated with *tab*(s) `\t`, simple sorting:

```
with open('yourfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    result = sorted(lines, key=lambda x: x[:x.find('\t')])
    for l in result:
        print(l)
```

The output:

```
1498        Pursuing it with eager feet, 
1498        And I must follow, if I can, 
1498        Until it joins some larger way
1498        The Road goes ever on and on
5181        not a penny-piece or a glass bead was given away.
5181        as well as the books, pictures were left in his possession.  
6220        written in golden ink. 
6220        There were many Bagginses and Boffins,
6220        of them had hardly ever been in Hobbiton before.
```

Comment: what if we consider 3 or 2 digits numbers as well?

Comment: @MarcusJames, what is the separator between id and text? tab , spaces?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there any way to solve this question with dictionaries?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
file_data = [[int(a), b] for a, b in [i.strip('\n').split('\t') for i in open('filename.txt')]]
for a, b in file_data:
   d[a].append(b)

for a, b in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[0]):
    print(a, b)
```

Without `defaultdict`:

```
d = {}
for a, b in file_data:
   if a not in d:
       d[a] = [b]
   else:
       d[a].append(b)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but is there any way without importing something?

Comment: it says ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: @MarcusJames are the spaces in your file tabs, or just spaces?

Comment: @MarcusJames This solution works when the numbes and sentences are separated by a tab, `\t`.

Comment: @MarcusJames please post what you get when you run `[i.strip('\n').split('\t') for i in open('filename.txt')]`

Comment: @MarcusJames Oh ok, glad to help!